# cannot lein ring uberwar with resource file: duplicate entry

Tags: clojure, resources, war, leiningen

I have a Clojure web server project for which I use the `uberwar` task for deployment.

It has worked well, until now when I try adding template xml files in the resources directory.

**Whenever I run `lein ring uberwar`, I get the following output:**

```
Compiling 28 source files to /Users/val/BandSquare/dev/digitick-booking-worker/target/classes
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: WEB-    INF/classes/saveCart2_addedsomesuffixthatcannotbeanywhereelse.xml
 at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry (ZipOutputStream.java:233)
    java.util.jar.JarOutputStream.putNextEntry (JarOutputStream.java:109)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor70.invoke (:-1)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke     (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:483)
    clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod (Reflector.java:93)
    clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod (Reflector.java:28)
    leiningen.ring.war$write_entry.invoke (war.clj:185)
    leiningen.ring.war$file_entry.invoke (war.clj:201)
    leiningen.ring.war$dir_entry.invoke (war.clj:206)
    leiningen.ring.uberwar$write_uberwar.invoke (uberwar.clj:48)
    leiningen.ring.uberwar$uberwar.invoke (uberwar.clj:74)
    leiningen.ring.uberwar$uberwar.invoke (uberwar.clj:62)
...
```

I have tried cleaning the project in every way I could imagine as suggested in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/leiningen/dMXCJeub80k).

I am sure I do not have duplicate source files, since it does not matter what I name the file under the `resources` directory, nor where I place it.

Below is the project layout:

[image: project layout]

And here is my `project.clj`:

```
(defproject digitick-booking-worker "1.7.1"
  :description "An RPC server to act as an adapter interface to the digitickBooking Web Service."
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [compojure "1.3.1"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.1.2"]
                 [http-kit "2.1.18"]
                 [org.jsoup/jsoup "1.8.2"] ; HTML DOM Manipulation
                 [selmer "0.8.2"]
                 [org.clojure/data.zip "0.1.1"]

                 [log4j "1.2.17" :exclusions [javax.mail/mail
                                              javax.jms/jms
                                              com.sun.jdmk/jmxtools
                                              com.sun.jmx/jmxri]]
                 [com.taoensso/timbre "3.1.6"]

                 [com.novemberain/langohr "3.0.1"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha"] ; asynchrony
                 [cheshire "5.3.1"] ;; JSON encoding library for Clojure. 

                 [bs/axis-ant "1.0"]
                 [bs/axis "1.0"]
                 [bs/commons-discovery "1.0"]
                 [bs/commons-logging "1.0"]
                 [bs/jaxrpc "1.0"]
                 [bs/log4j "1.0"]
                 [bs/saaj "1.0"]
                 [bs/wsdl4j "1.0"]
                 ]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.13"]]
  :ring {:handler digitick-booking-worker.handler/app
         :init digitick-booking-worker.handler/init}
  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                        [ring-mock "0.1.5"]]}}

  :repositories [["localrepo" "file:axisrepo"]]

  :java-source-paths ["digitick"]
  )
```

Any help much appreciated!

---

### Update

The problem disappears when I remove the `pom.xml` (which was generated using `lein pom`).

My guess is that the `lein ring uberwar` task somehow assigns itself duplicate jobs by taking both `project.clj` and `pom.xml` into account. (Should this be reported as a bug?)

Not marking the question as solved yet because I do not have a definite explanation.

Comment: At the command line, perform a search for this file. It may be related to an eclipse builder copying files around.

Comment: @cgrand: I just checked, this file does not get duplicated prior to the `lein ring uberwar` call. See my question update though.

Comment: I'm not sure about your specific problem, but in general I add `pom.xml` to my `.gitignore` file (or whatever vcs you're using), and generate it as needed using `lein pom`.  The pom is basically just for interop with maven repositories, but leiningen uses the `project.clj` for all its needs.

Comment: In my case, the `pom.xml` is for Counterclockwise. I do gitignore it, but this does not change the problem, it still interferes with `lein ring uberwar`

Comment: And I do generate it with lein pom.